# How to refactor nested case statements (in this case)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, switch-statement

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3. I have following `case` statements:

```
case
when private?
  case
  when not_active? then [:a, :b, :c, :d]
  when active?     then raise "private cannot be active"
  else raise "not recognized"
  end
when shared?
  case
  when not_active? then [:a, :b, :c]
  when active?     then raise "shared cannot be active"
  else raise "not recognized"
  end
when public?
  case
  when not_active? then [:a, :b]
  when active?     then [:a]
  else raise "not recognized"
  end
else raise "not recognized"
end
```

How to refactor the above code?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - I don't understand why you removed (at least) the `ruby-on-rails` tag since it may be that there is some RoR method that could help to refactor the code posted in the question.

Comment: could you explain more about the `active?` and `not_active?` methods ?
are they complements, I mean is it the case that `not_active? == !active?` ?

Comment: How can your code ever go to `raise "not recognized"`?

Comment: @Khaled - Yes, they are complements (not_active? == !active? # => true).

Comment: @oldergod - You could be right since method are complements.

Comment: I could be right? that is your code, you should know.

Comment: Great question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
raise "not recognized" unless private? or shared? or public?
raise "not recognized" unless not_active? or active?
raise "private cannot be active" if private? and active?
raise "shared cannot be active" if shared? and active?

[:a, *(:b unless active?), *(:c unless public?), *(:d if private?)]
```

---

By changing the error message, you can make it still more comfortable:

```
raise "visibility not recognized" unless private? or shared? or public?
raise "activeness not recognized" unless not_active? or active?
raise "active must be public" if active? and not public?

[:a, *(:b unless active?), *(:c unless public?), *(:d if private?)]
```

By the way, `inactive?` would be a better method name than `not_active?`.

Answer (score 0):

An organized one:

```
CONDITIONS = 
  {"private?" => {"not_active?" => [:a, :b, :c, :d],
                  "active?"     => "private cannot be active"},
  {"shared?"  => {"not_active?" => [:a, :b, :c],
                  "active?"     => "shared cannot be active"},
  {"public?"  => {"not_active?" => [:a, :b],
                  "active?"     => [:a]}}

def foo(it)
  value = "not recognised"
  CONDITIONS.each do |k, v|
    if it.send(k.to_sym)
      v.each do |inner_k, inner_v|
        if it.send(inner_k.to_sym)
          value = inner_v
        end
      end
    end
  end

  raise value if (value.class.name == "String")

  value
end
```

In case of expansion you only need to make the CONDITIONS hash larger.

Comment: Your approach seems to have "complicated" things rather than "facilitate" them, mostly when conditions (that is, when nested `case` statements) will increase in number.

Comment: You haven't specified the task completely then. :) Anyways, then use multi-leveled hash for the values.

Comment: What do you mean with and how you'd use "multi-leveled hash for the values"?

Comment: Yeee, but (again :-( ) it *seems* to have "complicated" things rather than "facilitate" them.

Comment: The requirements seems to be just as much complicated as it is. However as long as ou only use boolean functions to differenciate on, this solution is working, and as clean as it can. If that is not good enough then I can't help you now. Maybe first try to somehow calculate a single index, based on the decission, and apply that to a simple hash. But it's too late at night for me to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

DRY fetish:

```
class Public
  def not_active; [:a, :b]; end
  def active; not_active.first; end
  def missing_method; false; end
end

class Shared < Public
  def not_active; super << :c; end
  def active; raise "#{self.class.name.underscore} cannot be active"; end
end

class Private < Shared
  def not_active; super << :d; end
end

state = active? ? :active : (not_active? ? :not_active : :missing_method)
(Private.new.send(state) if private?)||
(Shared.new.send(state) if shared?)||
(Public.new.send(state) if public?)||raise("not recognized")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Array?

```
actions = [
    ['[:a, :b, :c, :d]', 'raise "private cannot be active"'],
    ['[:a, :b, :c]', 'raise "shared cannot be active"'],
    ['[:a, :b]', '[:a]']
]

x = [:private?, :shared?, :public?].find_index { |i| send(i) }
y = [:not_active?, :active?].find_index { |i| send(i) }

if x and y
    eval(actions[x][y])
else
    raise "not recognized"
end
```